# How to draw this block in tikz enviroment?

Tags: tikz-pic

I am looking for a way to draw these two blocks. Can someone help me here. 
For first block [image]

I was thinking of drawing

1. a rectangle
2. adding a scope to it

but I have no idea on how to draw this stair case.

Second block is

[image]

Comment: what you try so far?

Comment: If drawing the stair is the problem, why don't you add some code to draw the rectangle to give us something to start with?

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

[image]

it is not drawn as `pic` ... i found this images in collection of my answers, so you question is duplicate (unfortunately I din't make notes about questions).

**edit:** now are corrected blocks names and added note of limitation of the first proposed solution

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance= 5mm,
block/.style = {
    rectangle, draw, thick,
    minimum height=9mm, minimum width=12mm,
                  },
  sat/.style = {block,
        append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                \draw[gray]
                    ($(\LN.south)+(0,1mm)$) edge ($(\LN.north)+(0,-1mm)$)
                    ($(\LN.west) +(2mm,0)$)  to  ($(\LN.east) +(-2mm,0)$);
                \draw[very thick, opacity=0.75]
                    ($(\LN.south)+(-2mm, 2.5mm)$) -| (\LN.center) |-
                    ($(\LN.north)+( 2mm,-2.5mm)$);
                    }% end \pgfextra
                            },% end after command
                }
    ]
\node (X) [sat] at (0,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm,
 block/.style = {
    rectangle, draw, thick,
    minimum height=9mm, minimum width=12mm,
                  },
quant/.style = {block,
        append after command={
             \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                \draw[gray]
                    ($(\LN.south)+(0,1mm)$) edge ($(\LN.north)+(0,-1mm)$)
                    ($(\LN.west) +(2mm,0)$)  to  ($(\LN.east) +(-2mm,0)$);
                \draw[thick, opacity=0.75]
                    ($(\LN.center)+(-3.5mm,-3mm)$)
                        -| ++ (1mm,1mm) -| ++ (1mm,1mm) -| ++ (1mm,1mm)
                        -| ++ (1mm,1mm) -| ++ (1mm,1mm) -| ++ (1mm,1mm) -- ++ (1mm,0);
                    }% end \pgfextra
                            },% end after command
                }
    ]
\node (X) [quant] at (0,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**note:**

- for use of the above blocks you need to load tikz library `calc`.
- solution is not suitable in cases when you like to colored blocks. option `fill` cover content of  block. in this cases is better to use `path picture=` instead `append after command`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shadows}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box} % <-- added

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance= 5mm,
block/.style = {
    rectangle, draw, thick,
    minimum height=9mm, minimum width=12mm,
                  },
  sat/.style = {block,
     path picture={                         % <-- changed
                \draw[gray]
                    ($(\ppbb.south)+(0,1mm)$) edge ($(\ppbb.north)+(0,-1mm)$)
                    ($(\ppbb.west) +(2mm,0)$)  to  ($(\ppbb.east) +(-2mm,0)$);
                \draw[very thick, opacity=0.75]
                    ($(\ppbb.south)+(-2mm, 2.5mm)$) -| (\ppbb.center) |-
                    ($(\ppbb.north)+( 2mm,-2.5mm)$);
                    }% end path picture
                }
    ]
\node (X) [sat, fill=orange!10,drop shadow] at (0,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]